# What causes markers' locations to be inaccurate (by ~500 m) in shiny-leaflet map?

Tags: shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am trying to create a leaflet map as part of an R-Shiny project which displays circle markers at locations I previously geocoded from address information using the Google API. Putting the lon/lat values back into Google gives me the exact location of the address.

When I create the map from those lon/lat values in my shiny project using the code below, the marker positions are off in random directions by a few 100 meters (at maximum zoom level).

Based on google searches my guess is that it is something to do with markers changing position due to zoom level or with incompatible map projections.

```
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

alldata_sel = alldata  
if(input$dachverbandCheck != T){alldata_sel = filter(alldata_sel, Dachverband==input$dachverband)}
if(input$landkreisCheck != T){alldata_sel = filter(alldata_sel, Landkreis==input$landkreis)}
if(input$leistungstypCheck != T){alldata_sel = filter(alldata_sel, 
                                        LeistungstypBezeichnung==input$leistungstyp)}
if(input$traegerCheck != T){alldata_sel = filter(alldata_sel, Traegername==input$traeger)}

  #initialize map and setView
  leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 5, maxZoom = 18)) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(
    data = alldata_sel,
    lng=~longitude, # Longitude coordinates
    lat=~latitude, # Latitude coordinates
    radius=~KapRadius, 
    stroke=FALSE, # Circle stroke
    fillOpacity=0.5, # Circle Fill Opacity
    color = rgb(alldata_sel$colour_r, alldata_sel$colour_g, alldata_sel$colour_b,
                maxColorValue = 255)
  )
})
```

Comment: Can you provide an example coordinate where this is particularly pronounced?

Comment: One address is Pastors Kamp 1, 49626 Bippen, Germany. This was geocoded to lat=52.58204, lon=7.73484, which gives me the correct location when put back into google maps. The location in my leaflet map is at approx. 52.583943, 7.735384 which is about 210 meters from the true location. This is not the most extreme example, but already too inaccurate for my purposes.